# LED: Using the nonlinear region

Tags: led, diodes

Is it okay to use LEDs in the nonlinear (knee) region of:

- `V.f vs I.f` (forward voltage vs forward current)
- `I.v vs I.f` (light intensity vs forward current)

### Example

For example, from the Inolux IN-S66TFT5R5G5B datasheet:

[image: Inolux IN-S66TFT5R5G5B, (edited)]

**Note**: Please excuse the failure to flip the word order of the left-graph title.

Comment: Why do you think this might cause an issue?

Comment: Yes, it is OK. You won't hurt anything. It will actually save energy so if it's still bright enough for your application go for it.

Comment: It is ok to use LED in any region if it is not exceed maximum and still visible then it is used as indicator. Even low current is better for saving energy and prolonging device's life time.

Comment: *There is no knee* . https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/655076/forward-bias-voltage-of-diode/655157#655157

Comment: I've always thought LEDs are non-linear devices and operating in their non-linear region. What looks like a linear region to you is actually showing a small increase in voltage for a large increase in current, which is a non-linear relationship. The fairly linear relationship is between current and light output/intensity. Because of all of this, a recommended CURRENT is specified, and it is best for the LED's longevity to keep the operating current below that.

Comment: Perfectly OK | as long as you control the current by some means. || The current vs intensity curve is "just a commentary". It shows you the relative efficiency of the 3 LEDs as drive current changes. Most people take no account of that. People "designing with a vengeance" are aware of it but you use V & I to arrive at the desired result - the efficiency curve is liable to be not the starting point.

Comment: An issue to be aware of is that spectral wavelength may vary with drive current. Again - this is not something most users will notice when they 'design'.

Comment: @td127 : My concern was whether there might be other undepicted parasitics at low currents or at the knee (which @ Sredni Vashtar reminded is not a knee so much as an approximately natural logarithmic e^x relationship.)

Comment: I don't know of any parastics be they undepicted, depicted, or even picted. You might be overthinking this.

Comment: The "linear" region is where esr  (internal resistance) is more significant than change in diode voltage.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is it okay to use LEDs in the nonlinear (knee) region*

If you want to use the red LED at say 4 mA (in the knee region), you can see on the graph to the right that the relative luminous intensity is about 40% of the intensity when 20 mA is driving the LED. It's a simple case of knowing the driving current and looking on the right hand graph.

At 1 mA, the graph tells you that the relative luminous intensity is about 10% of the intensity when 20 mA are used. If you want to use it below 1 mA you should test it but, if it helps, many LEDs will still so visible light when operating around 100 μA although some are better than others.